# Различия floor() и trunc() из math

Tags: python, python-3.x

**math.floor(X)** - округление вниз *(до меньшего числа, я прав?)*

**math.trunc(X)** - усекает значение X *до целого*

В использовании есть разница, или функции повторяют друг друга?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Функции как минимум будут давать разные результаты на отрицательных числах:

```
from math import floor, trunc

print(floor(-3.2))   # Результат: -4
print(trunc(-3.2))   # Результат: -3
```

Answer (score 0):

Округление в меньшую сторону (до меньшего целого):

```
math.floor(2.567), math.floor(-2.567)
```

> (2, -3)

Усечение (отбрасываниe десятичных цифр):

```
math.trunc(2.567) , math.trunc(-2.567)
```

> (2, -2)

(c) Лутц